# Why MySQL connections remain in CLOSE_WAIT state for long time?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, c3p0

In my Spring MVC web application I use C3p0 for MySQL connection pooling. C3p0's `maxIdleTime` is set to 1500 seconds and at MySQL configuration `wait_timeout` is set to 1800 seconds.

My observation is, whenever I execute command `netstat -tanop` on ubuntu web server I see too many `CLOSE_WAIT` tcp connections to MySQL DB server.

[image]

If I run netstat on DB server to check whats going on then, the connection port which in `CLOSE_WAIT` state on web server is on `FIN_WAIT2` state on DB server. It remain for some time (60 Sec) and it get closed from DB server but on web server that connection is still remain in `CLOSE_WAIT` (mostly near about 7200 secs).

**Why connections on web server remain in `CLOSE_WAIT` state even if the same connection on DB server gets closed?**

I tried setting `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse` to 1 but nothing has changed.

I am confident about there is no DB connection leak in web application, because I enabled C3p0's properties that may help in finding DB leaks i.e.

```
debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces=true
unreturnedConnectionTimeout=30
```

This setting logs exception if connection is not closed for 30 seconds and it will consider as DB leak.

**UPDATE**

C3p0 properties configured in web App:

```
minPoolSize=10
acquireIncrement=1
maxPoolSize=500
initialPoolSize=10
numHelperThreads=100
maxIdleTime=2400
maxStatements=20
maxStatementsPerConnection=5
idleConnectionTestPeriod=120
acquireRetryAttempts=10
acquireRetryDelay=100
autoCommitOnClose=false
breakAfterAcquireFailure=false
testConnectionOnCheckout=true
testConnectionOnCheckin=true
preferredTestQuery =SELECT 1
debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces=true
unreturnedConnectionTimeout=30
```

Comment: Did you tried to use also different connection pool,as hikari? It also has a leak detection option

Comment: c3p0 ultimately calls `close()` on Connections asynchronously, in its internal thread pool. It is possible that the thread pool is getting backed up, leaving the Connections logically `close()`ed but not physically `close()`ed. if this is the issue (it is just a guess, and i'm not sure it quite fits), increasing c3p0's `numHelperThreads` setting might help.

Comment: @SteveWaldman well, currently `numHelperThreads` is set to 100. Do you still think I have to check after increasing it bit more? Post is updated will all C3p0 properties configured in web app.

Comment: I'd sooner suspect the MySQL Connector/J driver than this being a problem in C3P0, the socket can't reach CLOSE_WAIT unless the socket was closed, which would only happen if C3P0 has already closed the connection. Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using?

Comment: @Amogh no, if anything i’d adjust `numHelperThreads` down from that, the context switching overhead probably outweighs any additional concurrency long before 100. but i’d defer to Mark on `CLOSE_WAIT`, i don’t fully understand the conditions under which you would see that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In web application `mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar` is used, so MySQL Connector version is 5.1.25 along with C3p0 0.9.2

Comment: 5.1.25 is quite old (May 2013). Try upgrading to the latest 5.1.x (5.1.47 of August 2018) or even 8.0.x (8.0.13, October 2018). There doesn't seem to be a specific mention of this in the release notes though, but it wouldn't hurt to upgrade.